# robots.txt разрешить индексировать всё и всем роботам

Tags: robots.txt

Как правильно разрешить всем роботам индесировать всё:

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: /
```

или

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow:
```

или нет разницы?

Answer (score 1):

если ты хочешь чтобы все роботы индексировали всё, то удали *`robots.txt`* или выбери первый вариант (Подробнее можешь узнать на  [Яндекс.Справка](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/allow-disallow.html))